# getting NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

the table structure is as follows

+---------------+----------+-------------------+-------------+---------+--------+-------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+

> | REDEMPTION_ID | CCID     | MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER | POINTS_TYPE | PARTNER
>   | SCHEME | REDEMPTION_ORDER_STATUS | MEMBER_SEGMENT | PARTNER_POINTS |
>   MEMBERSHIP_FIRST_NAME | MEMBERSHIP_LAST_NAME | REDEMPTION_DATE     |
>   OUTBOUND_FILENAME | PRODUCT_TYPE |

+---------------+----------+--------
-----------+-------------+---------+--------+-------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------+

> |       1003740 | 21212103 | 1231237           | BASE        | QANTAS 
>   | Visa   | ORDERED                 | LEGACY         |    5000.000000 |
>   e                     | Name                 | 2017-10-23 10:26:51 |
>   NABQF05P.012      | CONSUMER     |
>
> |       1003741 | 21212103 |1231238           | BONUS       | QANTAS  | Visa   | ORDERED | LEGACY         |    2500.000000 | e            | Name
>   | 2017-10-23 10:26:51 | NABQF05P.012      | CONSUMER     |

I want to group the above rows based on the columns Membership_Number and POINTS_TYPE and the resulting row should be one row.

I am using the following query :

```
    select * from ((
    select * from NAB_REDEMPTION_DETAILS 
where PARTNER='QANTAS' and REDEMPTION_ORDER_STATUS IN ('PLACED','RESEND') and POINTS_TYPE  = 'BASE' group by MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER) a 
left OUTER JOIN (
        select * from NAB_REDEMPTION_DETAILS 
where PARTNER='QANTAS' and REDEMPTION_ORDER_STATUS IN ('PLACED','RESEND') and POINTS_TYPE  = 'BONUS' group by MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER) b on a.MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER=b.MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER) union (
        select * from (
        select * from NAB_REDEMPTION_DETAILS 
where PARTNER='QANTAS' and REDEMPTION_ORDER_STATUS IN ('PLACED','RESEND') and POINTS_TYPE  = 'BASE' group by MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER) c right OUTER JOIN (
        select * from NAB_REDEMPTION_DETAILS 
where PARTNER='QANTAS' and REDEMPTION_ORDER_STATUS IN ('PLACED','RESEND') and POINTS_TYPE  = 'BONUS' group by MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER) d on c.MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER=d.MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER)
```

when executing the query I am getting the above mentioned exception

Comment: Row 1) 1003740 | 21212103 | 1231237 | BASE | QANTAS | Visa | ORDERED | LEGACY | 5000.000000 | e | Name | 2017-10-23 10:26:51 | NABQF05P.012 | CONSUMER 



Row 2)  1003741 | 21212103 | 1231238 | BONUS | QANTAS | Visa | ORDERED | LEGACY | 2500.000000 | e | Name | 2017-10-23 10:26:51 | NABQF05P.012 | CONSUMER |

Comment: I am unable to see the "above mentioned exception". And, better format your question so people can take interest in it.

Comment: Kindly find the exception javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [REDEMPTION_ID] during auto-discovery

Comment: Hi. 1. Look at the formatted version of your message. Indent tables & code 4 spaces. 2. Clarify by editing your post, not in comments. 3. What are your comments for? 4. Google your error message without your specific names.  5. Read & act on [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thank you philipxy , but actually I have used stackoverflow and mostly the doubts that I have, would have already been answered but with this question the other answers are not upto my satisfaction. Here, I am doing the join on the same table. Thanks for formatting my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. since I was using joins in the same table and the Redemption_id was a Primarykey, It was resulting in the exception. I used group_concat instead of join and it solved my problem.

Kindly find the solution in the link  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc59a1/5